# Trouble reading japanese on websites

Tags: discussion, kanji

I'm using Meiryo UI for Japanese font in Firefox but its hard to read on some websites... Here is a picture of an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDrWd.png

Is this normal? Should I be using a different font? Which font?

Comment: Welcome to JLU! Just to let you know, generally questions regarding the Japanese language itself fit best on this site whereas resource related questions might be better off on the meta site.

Comment: Sorry for posting in the wrong section Chris. Thank you for the awareness! Should I delete this question?

Comment: No problem, it is just a common mistake. you can either delete this question and re-post it in the meta site. Or you can wait and leave it up to the community to see if it will be moved or not.

Comment: Thank you Chris.

Comment: @Chris: Issues arising in using computers are not in the scope of japanese.stackexchange.com, so I agree with your conclusion.  But I do not know what you mean by “resource related questions” in this case.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Meaning whether this question actually deals with resources or whether resource discussions belong on meta?

Comment: @Chris: The meaning of my comment is nothing more than what I wrote: I do not have any guess about what you meant by “resource related questions.”  I assume that you referred to Ryan’s question as a “resource related question,” but I do not see anything related to resource in Ryan’s question.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I see. I suppose because of the last line where the OP inquired about using "different fonts" I interpreted "fonts" as a "resource for how Japanese is displayed" compared to others.

Comment: @Chris: Now I understand your logic, but that is a very broad interpretation of the phrase “resource related questions”….

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I agree that it is a very broad interpretation. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how else to categorize the question..

Comment: @Chris: Categorize the question for what?  I do not think that categorizing this question as “resource related question” serves any purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's fairly normal.  I'm assuming that's from [Google ニュース](http://news.google.co.jp/), which on my OS X computer using Safari looks like this: (you may need to save the picture to get the full size)

> [image: Google News homepage]

It looks to me like Google is using MS Mincho for the font, not Meiryo, and the font size in the regions you drew boxes around is 11 pt for the gray text and 13 pt for the blue links.  (The bigger links for the articles in the center are using 16 pt.)

Personally, I always have to increase the font size when trying to read Kanji.  While I can handle 10-12 pt fonts in English, I typically have to go with 16-18 pt fonts in Japanese to make out enough details to read text.

I assume though, as your reading proficiency increases, it becomes easier to recognize kanji at smaller sizes based on general shape and context without having to zoom in to see every little stroke.  Just like how in English, you can read words without focusing on every individual letter.

Comment: Thanks Troyen. Just a small question but what font do you normally use for reading Japanese font in text files? The default font? Thanks.

Comment: I typically use whatever the default in the document is.  If I'm having a really hard time, I might change to a sans-serif font like Meiryo or MS Pゴシック (for Word) or something similar.  It doesn't change the size, but gets rid of some of the stylistic marks so I can see the character better.